# Calculate a date when total duration of multiple sub-intervals (within a larger interval) drops below X

Tags: algorithm, datetime, computer-science, intervals

I am building an expert system that will run as a web service (i.e. continuously).

Some of the rules in it are coded procedurally and deal with intervals — the rule processor maps over a set of user's **events** and calculates their total duration within a certain time-frame which is defined in relative terms (like *N years ago*). This result is then compared with a required threshold to determine whether the rule passes.

So for example the rule calculates for how long you were employed from 3 years ago to 1 year ago and passes if it's more than 9 months.

I have no problem calculating the durations. The difficult part is that I need to display to the user not simply whether the particular rule passed, but also the exact date when this "true" is due to become "false". Ideally, I'd love to display one more additional step ahead - i.e. when "false" switches back to "true" again — if there's data for this, of course. So on the day when the total duration of their employment for last year drops below 6 months the rule reruns, the result changes, and they get an email "hey, your result has just changed, you no longer qualify, but it 5 months you will qualify once again".

```
        |                              |                 |
_____|||1|||_______|||2|||__________|||3|||________|||4|||...
        |                              |                 |
    3 y. ago ---------------------- 1 y. ago            Now
    min 9 months work experience is required
```

In the example above the user qualifies, but is going not to, we need to tell them up front: "expect this to happen in 44 days" (also the system schedules a background job for that date) and when that will reverse back to true.

```
        |                              |                 |
____________________|1|__________________||||||||2||||||||...
        |                              |                 |
    3 y. ago ---------------------- 1 y. ago            Now
    min 9 months work experience is required
```

In this one the user doesn't qualify, we need to tell them when they are going to start to qualify.

```
        |                                                |
_____|||1|||___________|||||||2|||||||_________|||3|||____...
        |                                                |
    1 y. ago ------------------------------------------ Now
         at least 6 months of work experience is required
```

And here — when they are due to stop qualifying, because there's no event that is going on for them currently, so once these events roll to the left far enough, it's over until the user changes their CV and the engine re-runs with new dataset.

I hope it's clear what I want to do. Is there a smart algorithm that can help me here? Or do I just brute-force the solution?

## UPD:

The solution I am developing lies in creating a 2-dimensional graph where each point signifies a date (x-axis value) when the curve of *total duration for the timeframe* (y-axis value) changes direction. There are 4 such breakpoints for any given event. This graph will allow me to do a linear interpolation between two values to find when exactly the duration line crosses the threshold. I am currently writing this in Ruby.

Comment: In the examples where you're comparing "From 1 year ago --> Now", I don't see how anything you've discussed is actually possible? Unless you can predict the future, there's no way of knowing when someone will "qualify again" or "stop qualifying"? At best, you could say "you definitely won't qualify/stop qualifying within the next X months", it equivalently "it's *possible* that you *could* qualify/stop qualifying in X months".

Comment: The examples of "3 years ago --> 1 year ago" are doable ...although as with the "1 Year --> Now" examples, the result could very well be "it's *possible* that you *could* qualify/stop qualifying in X months"; there may not be any guaranteed date when qualification will begin/end. The question does strike me as a little far-fetched, but I could come up with an algorithm if you genuinely need to solve it.

Comment: No need to predict the future. On the first graph the user will stop qualifying soon after event #1 moves out of the frame. The user will start qualifying again some time after event #4 enters the timeframe of interest. After that obviously we don't need to predict anything, because the user is considered employed until further notice. Same goes for the chart #3 that you pointed to. Imagine: when event #2 starts going of of frame, the remaining part of it plus the whole event #3 are less than 6 months in total duration, so the user won't qualify at that point. I need to know when that happens.

Comment: To your other point, this whole thing may sound far-fetched, but counting total duration of person's employment that took place "from 3 years ago till now" is from real-life legislation on skilled migration. The examples of timeframes such as "between 3 and 5 years ago" are not in the law (that I know of) but I though it would be nice to have a more generalised algorithm that could deal with them as well.

Comment: I'm not debating that in *some* scenarios (such as the first one), you can get a definitive answer. My point was that in many scenarios you *do* need to "predict the future" to give a definitive answer, since - as you say yourself - *"the user is considered employed until further notice"*. (So by extension, I suppose you also assume that a person could be *unemployed* until further notice?)

Comment: Calculating this for timeframes such as "X months ago --> Now" Seems like a sensible problem to me, with the above caveat. (And clearly defined rules about what "assumptions" -- i.e. predictions of the future -- you're making.) However, I am inclined to think that the generalisation of "X months ago --> Y months ago" is an unnecessary complication; [You Aren't Gonna Need It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).